# make sprite animation using javascript (every 5s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to make my animation runs every 5sec using js

this is my html code

```
<div id="aa"></div>
```

and this is my css code

```
    #aa{
    width: 167px;
    height: 169px;
    background-image: url("sprite.png");
    /*animation: play .2s steps(6) ;*/
}
@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -1002px; }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umam2r83/zqjq4qot/1/)

Comment: You want a solution with css or with javascript ?! I think you want a css solution, so please change your title

Comment: i want code in javascript

Comment: You will find this here: Jquery FadeIn, FadeOut:
 http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadein

Comment: You want to change background position of image with javascript? Could you set real link to your sprite image (upload it somewhere), so we can get clearer picture about intentions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play animation in class, then add and remove class of element every 5 second.

```js
setInterval(function(){
    $("div").addClass("play");
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("div").removeClass("play");
    }, 1000);
}, 5000);
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}

.play {
    animation: play 1s;
}

@keyframes play {
    0% { margin-left: 0px; }
    50% { margin-left: 200px; }
    100% { margin-left: 0px; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It will look like:

```
function animation()
{
$('#overlay').fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
}
setInterval(animation,5000);
```

I made a sample for you, have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/xgnjy8st/

Answer (score 0):

Does this suite you?

```
<div id="aa"></div>

#aa {
    width: 167px;
    height: 169px;
    background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pineapple.jpg");
    animation: blinker 5s forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% { 
      opacity: 0.0; 
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/65t0ye2m/

Or try this one out with js

```
var img = document.getElementById('aa');

var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (img.style.visibility == 'visible') {
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
        img.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}, 1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/65t0ye2m/